# Reduce resolution of array through summation

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array like this:

```
a = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [ 5 ,6, 7, 8],
              [ 9,10,11,12],
              [13,14,15,16]])
```

I want to 'change the resolution', and end up with a smaller array, (say 2 rows by 2 cols, or 2 rows by 4 cols, etc.). I want this resolution change to happen through summation. I need this to work with large arrays, the number of rows, cols of the smaller array will always be a factor of the larger array.

Reducing the above array to a 2 by 2 array would result in (which is what I want):

```
[[ 14.  22.]
 [ 46.  54.]]
```

I have this function that does it fine:

```
import numpy as np

def shrink(data, rows, cols):
    shrunk = np.zeros((rows,cols))
    for i in xrange(0,rows):
        for j in xrange(0,cols):
            row_sp = data.shape[0]/rows
            col_sp = data.shape[1]/cols
            zz = data[i*row_sp : i*row_sp + row_sp, j*col_sp : j*col_sp + col_sp]
            shrunk[i,j] = np.sum(zz)
    return shrunk

print shrink(a,2,2)
print shrink(a,2,1)
#correct output:
[[ 14.  22.]
 [ 46.  54.]]
[[  36.]
 [ 100.]]
```

I've had a long look through the [examples](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc), but can't seem to find anything that helps.

Is there a faster way to do this, without needing the loops?

Comment: If it works fine, what is your question?

Comment: @Niek de Klein - edited to clarify. I'm after a faster method to do this.

Comment: People wanting to do this kind of stuff tend to use the `itertools` module, it might be worth taking a look.

Comment: This question may find better answers at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With your example:

```
a.reshape(2,2,2,2).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=2)
```

returns:

```
array([[14, 22],
       [46, 54]])
```

Now let's create a general function…

```
def shrink(data, rows, cols):
    return data.reshape(rows, data.shape[0]/rows, cols, data.shape[1]/cols).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=2)
```

works for your examples:

```
In [19]: shrink(a, 2,2)
Out[19]: 
array([[14, 22],
       [46, 54]])

In [20]: shrink(a, 2,1)
Out[20]: 
array([[ 36],
       [100]])
```

Comment: This is amazingly "Numpythonic".

Comment: @eumiro you got a small mistake in function definition, you use `a` instead of `data`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm sure there is a better/smarter approach without all these horrendous loops...

Here is one way to avoid explicitly looping over every element of `data`:

```
def shrink(data, rows, cols):
  row_sp = a.shape[0] / rows
  col_sp = a.shape[1] / cols
  tmp = np.sum(data[i::row_sp] for i in  xrange(row_sp))
  return np.sum(tmp[:,i::col_sp] for i in xrange(col_sp))
```

On my machine, this is about 30% faster than your version (for `shrink(a, 2, 2)`).

Comment: +1 thanks very much, cool way of doing it, but eumiro nailed this one.